# Python receiving data via socket and forwarding it via web socket

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, tornado

Being completely new to web sockets and relatively new to Python, I was wondering if it is possible to write a server (or if one already exists, that would be even better) in Python that receives data via a standard socket (UDP) and forwards that data via web sockets to a browser?  I notice in using Tornado, that the last line of your main is typically:

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Which creates a "listener" loop and would seem to prevent me from receiving any data on my standard socket.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Tornado doesn't have any explicit APIs for dealing with UDP, but you can add a UDP socket with `IOLoop.add_handler` (the following code is untested but should give you the basic idea):

```
def handle_udp(sock, events):
    while True:
        try:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(bufsize)
            # do stuff with data
        except socket.error as e:
            if e.errno in (errno.EAGAIN, errno.WOULDBLOCK):
                # nothing more to read, return to the IOLoop
                return

sock = bind_udp_socket()
sock.setblocking(0)
IOLoop.current().add_handler(sock, IOLoop.READ)
IOLoop.current().start()
```